# Cannot get rid of background picture when using Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, chartkick

I'm using chartkick in a rails 4.1, and for some reason I cannot change the background image!

My config file enacts everything except for the background transparency.  Any assistance would be excellent.

My config file:

> Chartkick.options = {
>       library: {
>         legend: { enabled: true },
>         exporting: { enabled: false },
>         backgroundColor: "transparent",
>         height: "300px",
>         width: "200px",
>         colors: ["#2c3e50", "#2980b9", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b"]
>       }
>   }

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [google charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/) with Chartkik, you can't use *transparent* on that property. You can check the documentation on individual chart options, like here on the [PieChart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options):

> **backgroundColor**
>
> - The background color for the main area of the chart. Can be either a simple HTML color string, for example: 'red' or '#00cc00', or an
>     object with the following properties:
>
>   - backgroundColor.stroke:   The color of the chart border, as an HTML color string.
>   - backgroundColor.strokeWidth: The border width, in pixels.
>   - backgroundColor.fill: The chart fill color, as an HTML color string.

Comment: Ah gotcha thanks! When I take it out of dev into staging env it doesn't have it anyway, only just discovered this.